Huge memory consumption when iterating systemd journal
Dear community, here are the story description and 2 questions:
I'm trying to fix significant memory consumption in a systemd (--version is 250) journal forwarding application. Our application is similar to the example on this page:  https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/sd_journal_process.html. The main difference is that our application forwards logs to a backend instead of printing them.
But: even when running the "official" example on our system, memory consumption grows rapidly, reaching 250+ MB in 20 minutes, as shown by systemctl status.
systemctl status output:
~# systemctl status journal-forwarder
* journal-forwarder.service - journal-forwarder
     Loaded: loaded (8;;file://lib/systemd/system/journal-forwarder.service/lib/systemd/system/journal-forwarder.service8;;; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)8;;
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-04-29 10:52:57 UTC; 20min ago
   Main PID: 3120 (journal-forward)
     Memory: 266.4M
        CPU: 51.136s
     CGroup: /system.slice/journal-forwarder.service
             `- 3120 /usr/bin/journal-forwarder

Using top, I see that shared libraries, not the application itself, are the main memory consumers. Here's the top output after 20 minutes of operation:
top - 11:18:02 up 17:35,  2 users,  load average: 0.92, 1.31, 1.77
Tasks: 152 total,   3 running, 149 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  9.5 us, 10.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 68.8 id, 11.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :    996.4 total,     91.0 free,    103.1 used,    802.3 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.    864.7 avail Mem 

 PID  USER   VIRT    RES    SHR     S    %CPU  %MEM  COMMAND                                                                                                          
 3120 root   527012  251704 251196  S     0.0  24.7  journal-forward                                                                                                  
 309  root   125760  92008  91116   S     0.0   9.0  systemd-journal                                                                                                  
 2598 root   61852   17124  10172   S     1.3   1.7  app1                                                                                                  
 666  root   36504   11900   8396   S     3.1   1.2  app2                     

RES (Resident Set Size) is the portion of the process's memory held in RAM. SHR (Shared Memory Size) is the portion of the process's memory shared with other processes. The private memory of the application RES - SHR is only a few hundred KB, which makes sense given the application's small code and data size.
I think - it is a problem. Why?
SHR contributes to RES memory (and as a result to the overall memory consumption of the application). From systemd point of view, the memory consumption of the application grows continuously. If I let our application running without systemd memory limit(MemoryHigh / MemoryMax), it gets to 700MB (from 1GB that we have) and the board makes reset. We saw, that the application can run with systemd memory limit of 20MB for a long time, but we are afraid of out-of-memory-kliier being called at some point.
-> FIRST QUESTION: Is it a problem, that memory consumption grows?
I found some workaround to cause shared memory regions to be unmapped periodically. I see, if I periodically close (sd_journal_close())and reopen (sd_journal_open()) the journal handle, the SHR memory size is released. Of course, we need to maintain the state etc, but the major problem is "solved".
-> SECOND QUESTION: Is there an alternative API within systemd that can achieve the same effect? Specifically, does the systemd library provide a direct API to explicitly unmap unused shared memory regions?

Dear community!
We found some workaround to cause shared memory regions to be unmapped periodically. We see, that if we periodically close and reopen the journal handle, it releases the memory. Of course, we need to maintain the state and so on, but the major problem is "solved".
The question, maybe the systemd library provides a direct API to unmap the not used shared memory regions explicitly? Is there a known alternative API within systemd to achieve the same effect?
